# Keyboard safe area wrong for iPad in multitasking Slide Over (SwiftUI/UIKit)

Tags: ios, ipad, swiftui, uikit

I've got a view with content on the bottom edge, which gets partially obscured by the keyboard when the app is in Slide Over. This isn't the case in side-by-side multitasking or when the app is full screen.

[image: Slide over with keyboard]

All other configurations are fine:

**Side-by-side, with keyboard:**
[image]

**Slide over, without keyboard:**
[image: Slide over without keyboard]

Here's the example view code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(.title)
        }
    }
}
```

I've noticed this issue in SwiftUI lifecycle apps, UIKit lifecycle apps, across different iOS versions (including iOS 14) and on all iPad sizes.

I've seen solutions that check the `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` and the window bounds to check if the app is in Slide Over and adjust the UI, but I'm using SwiftUI and I'd like to avoid this kind of hack. Any advice on how to deal with this?